# Getting Error: when IOS device connects to server

Tags: ios, websocket

we have a problem when connecting  ios device to server  Getting black screen and error from iphone Chrome console :`Websocket network error The operation couldn't be complated osstatus:-9801`.But sometimes same version of ios  can  connect to server  without  any   problem.

What we did  to slove this problem:

1.Changed SSL

2.Run server without any security (without SSL certificate)

3.Changed  Websocket Library

4.Tested with other Browsers.

We assumed that was SSL fault because we have blocked access from foreign sites.
But when we tested with sslChecker it says  we don't had any   ssl on server.